# Python Flask The CSRF session token is missing (Chrome Web Browser)

Tags: python, flask, csrf, flask-wtforms

I have an error with Chrome Web Browser. I get this error message: "The CSRF session token is missing.". The token is correct with Flask-WTf .. CSRFProtect.
With Firefox Web Browser still work but no Chrome and Safari Web Browser.

Helps please and thanks

[[image]

Comment: I tried with this example still no working. https://nickjanetakis.com/blog/fix-missing-csrf-token-issues-with-flask

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the source code of the page? There should be a hidden field containing the CSRF token.
AFAIK Flask-wtf will automatically handle this for you. Either pass a form instance to your template to build the form automatically, or add this in the template: `{{ form.csrf_token }}` if you prefer to add the HTML controls yourself and bind them to form data.

Comment: Ain't a CSRF or csrf_token token missing. It is a CSRF session token is missing.

Comment: I overwrited flask-security LoginForm.validate() to raise ValueError(session) and i get this with Firefox but no Chrome: ValueError: <SqlAlchemySession {'_permanent': True, '_fresh': False, 'csrf_token': 'd8ed69d947a40b9a519453df0155bfcf3586f92b'}>